# Using AWS CodeArtifact CredentialProvider with .Net Core - Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, dotnet-tool, aws-codeartifact

Last week I followed [this AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/nuget-cli.html) to set up my dotnet CLI to use AWS Code Artifact with the Credential Provider. This can be done with 3 commands:

1. `dotnet tool install -g AWS.CodeArtifact.NuGet.CredentialProvider`
2. `dotnet codeartifact-creds install`
3. `dotnet codeartifact-creds configure set profile profile_name`

This all worked as expected and I was able to publish packages to AWS CodeArtifact from the dotnet CLI.

However today when I try to use the `codeartifact-creds` command I get an error suggesting that dotnet doesnt know about the command:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-codeartifact-creds does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

Any help on fixing this and being able to use the tool would be appriciated.

---

What I've tried:

- Restarting my machine
- Remove tool via CLI `dotnet tool uninstall AWS.CodeArtifact.NuGet.CredentialProvider`, then reinstall using the 3 command above
- Remove tool manually by deleting from `%home%/.dotnet/tools` then reinstalling

Worth mentioning:

- I'm running Debian in a WSL2 environment on Windows 10
- The only thing that changed since this last worked (AFAIK) was that I restarted my machine, nothing else.
- I have both dotnet core 3.1 and 5 SDKs installed

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that the path to the dotnet tools folder was no longer included in my `$PATH` variable after a reboot.

Updating the `$PATH` variable to include the dotnet tools folder (`%home%/.dotnet/tools`) fixes the issue.

Comment: For anyone looking at how to do this, it's ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"